# Empty response received error in php-sdk sample for http canvas url

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Error trying to get the basic facebook app running on the facebook page.

Downloaded https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk
Created new app and created index.php as copy of example.php.
Provided Site URL and Canvas URL and other default settings

Now testing this app "site URL" is working as fine when I goto canvas url (http://apps.facebook.com/myfbapp/)to test page on facebook I get the error:

Error
Error while loading page from myfbapp
Empty response received.

The same error for HTTP and HTTPS. Any idea why this is happening? I haven't added any of my code yet am trying to get   the basic setup running out of the box from php-sdk.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your Apps in secure server hosting, include activated SSL.

Can't use standard web hosting.